# ValueError: wrapper loop when unwrapping

Tags: python, doctest

Python3 test cases (doctests) are failing with my sample code. But the same is working fine in Python2.

`test.py`:

```py
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, a=0):
        self.a = a

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return Test(a=str(self.a) + attr)
```

`tst.py`:

```py
from test import Test

t = Test()
```

Run test cases: `python3 -m doctest -v tst.py`

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/doctest.py", line 2787, in <module>
    sys.exit(_test())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/doctest.py", line 2777, in _test
    failures, _ = testmod(m, verbose=verbose, optionflags=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/doctest.py", line 1950, in testmod
    for test in finder.find(m, name, globs=globs, extraglobs=extraglobs):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/doctest.py", line 933, in find
    self._find(tests, obj, name, module, source_lines, globs, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/doctest.py", line 992, in _find
    if ((inspect.isroutine(inspect.unwrap(val))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 513, in unwrap
    raise ValueError('wrapper loop when unwrapping {!r}'.format(f))
ValueError: wrapper loop when unwrapping <test.Test object at 0x7f6e80028550>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is arguably a bug in doctest. What's happening is that doctest is searching for functions/methods/callables with a docstring, and while doing so it's [unwrapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.unwrap) any decorators it finds. Why it does this, I have no idea. But anyway, doctest ends up calling `inspect.unwrap(t)` (where `t` is a `Test` instance), which is essentially equivalent to doing this:

```
while True:
   try:
       t = t.__wrapped__
   except AttributeError:
       break
```

Because `t` is a `Test` instance, accessing `t.__wrapped__` calls `__getattr__` and returns a new `Test` instance. This would go on forever, but `inspect.unwrap` is smart enough to notice that it's not getting anywhere, and throws an exception instead of entering an infinite loop.

---

As a workaround, you can rewrite your `__getattr__` method to throw an `AttributeError` when `__wrapped__` is accessed. Even better, throw an AttributeError when *any* dunder-attribute is accessed:

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    if attr.startswith('__') and attr.endswith('__'):
        raise AttributeError
    return Test(a=str(self.a) + attr)
```

Comment: Well, cheers for this one :) Has this bug been somehow filed to `doctest` now? Still here in 2018.

Comment: @iago-lito No idea. I have neither reported it nor searched for an existing bug report.

Comment: There is a bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue35753. It's marked "Stage: resolved" but it's still "Status: open".

Comment: bugs.python.org/issue35753 has been merged and will be part of python3.10

Answer (score 8):

For `unittest.mock` try importing items as

```
from unittest import mock
```

instead of

```
from unittest.mock import patch
```

This worked around the bug for me.