# Error when importing mock.call if doctest are enabled

Tags: python, pytest

When I have *doctest* enabled and import `call` I get this exception:

```py
/usr/lib/python3.6/doctest.py:933: in find
    self._find(tests, obj, name, module, source_lines, globs, {})
/usr/lib/python3.6/doctest.py:992: in _find
    if ((inspect.isroutine(inspect.unwrap(val))
/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py:516: in unwrap
    raise ValueError('wrapper loop when unwrapping {!r}'.format(f))
E   ValueError: wrapper loop when unwrapping call
```

Call imported like this:

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, call
```

I looked at this question [ValueError: wrapper loop when unwrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271586/valueerror-wrapper-loop-when-unwrapping). Rewriting `__getattr__` does not look like a clean solution for me.

I import and use `call` differently, as a workaround, which helps:

```py
from unittest import mock

...
mock.call(1)
...
```

I wonder are there any better/cleaner options to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49271586/11301900) question? A quick google search lead me to this: https://bugs.python.org/issue35753.

Comment: @AMC I did check this one. I wonder are there any other options